# Calculate the age for a Opportunity Stage?

Tags: formula, opportunity

How to calculate the age for a Opportunity Stage. If it's open, how many days was it open. If it was X how many days was it in X stage?

A workflow to field update a when a stage name chang
I have researched and found out that I need to create a report instead. But all I need is a field value in days. Is it possible?

Comment: Create a field, called last stage change, with date time type. Create a workflow that set that field to now in case if stage has been changed.  Create a formula field that calculate the difference between now and last stage change field in days. Done)

Comment: We have taken this a step further. Using stage history we update a related record to calculate the number of days the record spent in each stage along with how many times it has been in that stage      Executed on stage change and daily via batch. you can keep it simple and know days since last change or more complex.

Comment: @kurunve can u update this comment as an answer? Thanks!

Comment: I think that you can use something like Analytic Snapshots to accomplish this. Check this page that it explains how to do this:Prepare Reporting Snapshots